# como chamar a função de arquivo .js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, script

não estou conseguindo chamar uma função javascript de um arquivo. Ex:

Arquivo: `javascript` dentro da pasta `raiz/scripts/javascript.js`

```
function responsivo () {
    $('#responsivo').popover({
        //trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        title: 'O que é um site ou software responsivo?',
        content: $('#Responsivo').html()
    }).popover("show");
};
```

`view` que está na pasta `raiz/views/home/Index.cshtml`

```
<h3 class="div1Texto2">Sites, Softwares e Lojas Virtuais 100% integrados e <span id="responsivo">responsivos</span></h3>
```

apontamento na tag `head`:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

quando eu rodo a página ele não funciona, porém se eu colocar aquela função na página ela funciona normalmente.

tentei fazer assim também, mas não funcionou:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    responsivo();
</script>
```

**obs:** consegui chamar colocando onload="responsivo()" na tag , mas se tiver muitas funções como faço?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar usar duas alternativas, ou o **caminho relativo**, que é em relação ao arquivo atual. Então se esta é a localização do seu index : `raiz/views/home/` então o caminho para seu arquivo js, seria `<script src="../../scripts/javascript.js"></script>`. A cada `../` é como se fosse voltar uma pasta para trás. 
A outra alternativa seria utilizar o **caminho absoluto**, que é colocar o link da onde esta localizado o arquivo, seria algo como: `<script src="http://www.seusite.com/scripts/javascript.js"></script>`.
Acho que é isso, espero ter ajudado. Não compreendi a sua observação...comente aquui

Comment: Fiz assim <body onload="responsivo ()">

Comment: e dessa forma, funcionou?

Comment: Ainda não testei, estou na rua agora, mas chegando eu vou testar. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Blz, qualquer coisa só comentar. E no caso de utilizar as funções nas tags, você poderia usar Jquery tambem.... sem precisar colocar direto na tag

Comment: @Fabio Souza também tenho este problema. Estou usando windows e não sei se usa-se \ ou / para entrar em subpastas. Quando ponho o código javascript diretamente no html funciona.